# How to validate JWT token against more than one Azure Active Directories (ClientIds)?

Tags: jwt, azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-2.0

I have an Asp.Net Core 2.0 WebApi, which requires all requests to be authenticated and it uses JWT token validation like this:

`services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                        .AddJwtBearer(options =>
                                    {
                                        options.Authority = this._configuration.GetValue<string>("Authority");
                                        options.Audience = this._configuration.GetValue("ClientId");
                                    });
...
app.UseAuthentication();`

I also have two Client applications: Angular4 web app and Web Api.

All three applications have their own AAD App Registration = each has different ClientID but all are on the same Tenant(Authority).

Is it possible to set the Web Api app the way, it validates the token against more than one AAD (the token can be generated by three different AAD = three different ClientIDs)?

I know I can generate token on client using the 'client_credentials' flow and use that token to make an Api call, but I would have to deal with token refresh etc. So, I just wonder, if there is any easier way.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pay attention to the different client ids . No matter in which client , when acquire an access token to call your web api which secured by AAD , the `audience` claim in access token should be the same : App ID URI you registered for API app .  API side should validate that the audience claim in access token matches App ID URI of web api , it doesn't care which client send the access request .